# Subscribing to events calendar updates

Tags: views, datetime

I've implemented an events calendar to my drupal 7 site. How would I offer the option for users to subscribe for event calendar updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options, for example:

1. Provide an RSS feed of the calendar events.
2. Provide email notifications with something like http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas
I am trying to make sense of the subscriptions module.

How would I go about enabling the rss feed of the calendar events?

Comment: For email notifications, users would subscribe to the taxonomy term for the event

Comment: Thank you. So setting up taxonomy is compulsory? @DavidThomas